# Constrainted typealias doesn't use constraints

Tags: swift, generics, type-alias

This works:

```
protocol Walkable {
    init()
}

class Animal {
    init(someProperty: Int) {}
}

class WalkableAnimal: Animal, Walkable {
    required init() {
        super.init(someProperty: 0)
    }
}

class Person {
    init() {
        InitializeAWalkableAnimal(walkableAnimal: WalkableAnimal.self)
    }

    func InitializeAWalkableAnimal<T: Animal>(walkableAnimal: T.Type) where T: Walkable {
        let animal = walkableAnimal.init()
    }
}
```

However, I want to avoid the WalkableAnimal subclass entirely. I just want to create a `Cat` `class` that inherts from `Animal` and conforms to `Walkable` protocol. Furthermore, I can not pass `Cat` directly as parameter because the types are dynamic. I would expect something like this should work:

```
protocol Walkable {
    init()
}

class Animal {
    init(someProperty: Int) {}
}

class Cat: Animal, Walkable {
    required init() {
        super.init(someProperty: 0)
    }
}

class Dog: Animal, Walkable {
    required init() {
        super.init(someProperty: 1)
    }
}

typealias AnyWalkableAnimal = (Animal & Walkable).Type

class Person {
    init(anyWalkableAnimal: AnyWalkableAnimal) {
        // ERROR
        InitializeAWalkableAnimal(walkableAnimal: anyWalkableAnimal.self)
    }

    func InitializeAWalkableAnimal<T: Animal>(walkableAnimal: T.Type) where T: Walkable {
        let animal = walkableAnimal.init()
    }
}

class PersonCaller {
    init() {
        Person(anyWalkableAnimal: Cat.self)
        Person(anyWalkableAnimal: Dog.self)
    }
}
```

The error is:

> Instance method 'InitializeAWalkableAnimal(walkableAnimal:)' requires
>   that 'Animal' conform to 'Walkable'

This is nonsense since the `typealias` doesn't allow types that aren't `Walkables` right? Why is the compiler not happy? Is there any way I can just pass around any type that conforms to both `Animal` and `Walkable`? Why is the `typealias` not working? The `typealias` explictily mentions that the type that it takes must be an `Animal` and `Walkable`. It works the other way around (as expected): when I try to pass in an `Animal` that does not conform to `Walkable`, the initializer gives a compile error.

I am developing on the Swift Development Toolchain 25 December 2018 if that makes any difference.

Comment: [Protocols don't always conform to themselves](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43408193/2976878) – in your case, `Walkable` cannot conform to itself because it has an `init()` requirement. Consider what should happen if you called `T.init()` within `InitializeAWalkableAnimal`, what type should be constructed? `T` would be of type `Animal & Walkable`, which doesn't provide a static type that can be initialised conforming to `Walkable`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see why `InitializeAWalkableAnimal` needs to be generic at all.

```
protocol Walkable {
    init()
}

class Animal {
    init(someProperty: Int) { }
}

class Cat: Animal, Walkable {
    required init() { super.init(someProperty: 0) }
}

class Dog: Animal, Walkable {
    required init() { super.init(someProperty: 1) }
}

typealias Pet = Animal & Walkable
typealias PetType = Pet.Type

class Person {
    init(petType: PetType) {
        initPet(petType: petType)
    }

    func initPet(petType: PetType) {
        let pet = petType.init()
        print("I got a pet: \(pet)")
    }
}

class PersonCaller {
    init() {
        Person(petType: Cat.self)
        Person(petType: Dog.self)
    }
}

_ = PersonCaller()
```

Output:

```
I got a pet: __lldb_expr_8.Cat
I got a pet: __lldb_expr_8.Dog
```

Comment: Not sure why I didn't came up to this myself :/